# ввод с клавиатуры двух значений через пробел

Tags: python

Нужно чтобы вводились два значения через пробел.
как реализовать через enter, я разобрался

```
a, b = int(input()), int(input())
```

могу создать список из целых чисел вводимых через пробел

```
lst = list(map(int, input().split()))
```

но тут загвоздка. Как ограничить ввод только двумя значениями? И потом это лишнее действие присваивания значений списка новым переменным. Наверняка существует способ сделать это в одну строчку.

Answer (score 5):

Итератор `map` можно "распаковать" в пару переменных:

`a, b = map(int, input().split())`

Comment: как раз то что надо!

Comment: Хорошо бы упомянуть, что это распаковка называется )